# How can I get the Appstore to popup within my app upod clicking an AD

Tags: ios, app-store, ads

I have been on apps before that have opened the Appstore within the app upon clicking an AD and was wondering how to do this or what makes this happen. Not sure if it is configured in the AD platform being used or if those ads have special code attached to them. It would be nice to have this happen to all the ads on my app as it seems more efficient than open the appstore app separately. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SKStore view controller.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html